# Proof by induction: $a_n > n + \frac{1}{3} \space \forall n \in N,\space n\geq 4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

**How do I prove this by induction?**

Let $(a_n)_{n\in N}$ be the sequence defined by:

$$a_1=1,\space a_2=\frac{3}{2},\space a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+\frac{2n+1}{n+2}a_n \space \space (n\in N)$$

Prove that $a_n > n + \frac{1}{3} \space \forall n \in N,\space n\geq 4$

**Here's what I did, is it ok?**

**1) I define**

> $$P(n): a_n > n + \frac{1}{3} \space \forall n \in N,\space n\geq4\\$$

**2) Since the base case is true,**

$$a_1=1, \ a_2=\frac{3}{2},\ a_3=\frac{5}{2},\ a_4=5 $$

$$P(4):a_4 = 5 > 4+\frac{1}{3}$$

**3) I assume $P(n)$ (already defined) and**

> $$P(n+1):a_{n+1}>n+1+\frac{1}{3} = n + \frac{4}{3}$$

**are true, and want to prove that it implies**

> $$P(n+2):a_{n+2}>n+2+\frac{1}{3}=n+\frac{7}{3}$$

**is true.**

**4)So since:**

by the second induction hypothesis,

$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+\frac{2n+1}{n+2}a_n > n+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2n+1}{n+2}a_n\ $$

and by the first induction hypothesis,

$$n+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2n+1}{n+2}a_n > n+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2n+1}{n+2}(n + \frac{1}{3}) = n+\frac{4}{3} + \dfrac{2n^2+n+\dfrac{2n}{3}+\dfrac{1}{3}}{n+2} $$

**5)Now as I know that every term is positive I can remove some terms and assure that:**

$$n+\frac{4}{3} + \dfrac{2n^2+n+\dfrac{2n}{3}+\dfrac{1}{3}}{n+2} > n+\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2n+1}{n+2}(n + \frac{1}{3}) = n+\frac{4}{3} + \dfrac{2n^2}{n+2}$$

**So the only step remaining would be making sure that:**

$$\dfrac{4}{3}+\dfrac{2n^2}{n+2} > \dfrac{7}{3}\ $$

then

$$ \dfrac{2n^2}{n+2} > 1 which \ is \ true \ \forall n \in N, n \geq 4$$

**Therefore $P(n+2)$ is true, $P(n+1)$ is true and also $P(n)$ is true.**

Comment: $a_3=a_2+\frac{7}{5}a_1 = \frac{29}{10}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: [Previous comment was deleted]. Sure, but you said $a_3=5/2$, and $29/10 \neq 5/2$

Comment: @pendermath by definition of the sequence when $a_{n+2}=a_3,\ n=1$ so, $with\ a_1=1,\ a_2=\frac{3}{2},\ explicitly \  a_3=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{2*1+1}{1+2}1 = \frac{5}{2}$

Comment: Thanks. So yes, I was missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct. A shortcut would be to notice that 
$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+\frac{2n+1}{n+2}a_n > n+\frac{4}{3}+ \underbrace{\frac{2n+1}{n+2}a_n}_{\geq 1} > n+\frac{4}{3}+1 = n + \frac{7}{3}$$
since we have that $a_n > 4 + \frac{1}{3} > 1$ and $\frac{2n+1}{n+2} > 1$ are true for all $n \geq 4$. Hence, $\frac{2n+1}{n+2}a_n >1$ for all $n \geq 4$.